# How can I create a database in mongodb and import the data from a csv to its collection

Tags: mongodb

I am not able to figure out,how to create a database in mongodb. 
When I login in to the mongo console it shows me test database as default. What are the steps to create a new database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we login into mongo without passing any parameter, say db or hostname, it will automatically connect you with test db.

In order to create DB and dump data from CSV you can use the following command :-

```
mongoimport --db nxtshow --collection movies --type csv --file ./mongo/movies.csv --fields id,imdb_url,release_date,title,video_release_date
```

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB, to create a database from within the **[Mongo shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/mongo/)** you use

```
use mydatabasename
```

where `mydatabasename` is the name you want to give to the database. If you want to list the databases

```
show dbs
```

The [shell quick reference documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongo-shell/) is pretty good.

For importing data from a CSV file, you can use **[mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)**